# Scriptable Object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I'm a quite confused about Scriptable Objects. For example, can I use 'new' when I create a Scriptable Object? If I can't use 'new', how can I use it, and how do the code examples I provided below work?

This is my Player script that detects when the player touches the Item.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Inventory inventory;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Item"))
        {
            int itemId = collision.GetComponent<ItemWorld>().item.id;
            string  itemName = collision.GetComponent<ItemWorld>().item.name;
            int itemAmount  = collision.GetComponent<ItemWorld>().item.amount;
            inventory.AddItem(itemId,itemName,itemAmount);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ScriptableObject script that hold Items attributes.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Item", menuName ="ItemSystem/BasicItem")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int amount;

    public Item(int _id,string _name,int _amount) {

        this.id = _id;
        this.name = _name;
        this.amount = _amount;
    }
}
```

Here is an inventory script that adds items to a list based on incoming values.

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> InventoryList = new List<Item>();

    public void AddItem(int _itemId,string _itemName, int _itemAmount)
    {
        Item newItem = new Item(_itemId,_itemName,_itemAmount);
        InventoryList.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

I learned on Internet that I can create Scriptable Objects using CreateInstance, but I didn't fully understand how to do it.

Comment: Check out the manual for [Scriptable Objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).